# FFTW _GNUC_ is not defined as a preprocessor macro

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, fftw

I have linked a `FFTW` library to the Unreal Engine project from [this](http://www.fftw.org) website. But now when I try to include the header file to my project, I get error:

> '__GNUC__' is not defined as a preprocessor macro,
>   replacing with '0' for '#if/#elif'

I have no idea how to fix this. I don't want to mess with the code itself, because I think it is perfectly fine. Did I forget something when linking the library? I've also tried including the header file as a C library.
Any help would be appreciated.

IDE: Visual Studio 2017 Community

OS: Windows 10 Pro 64x

UE4 Version: 4.20

Comment: Given your error, I think you'll need to also provide your environment. Compiler and OS at a minimum. Good luck!

Comment: `__GNUC__` is not defined when compiling with VS (These macros are defined by all GNU compilers that use the C preprocessor: C, C++, Objective-C and Fortran) - from https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html
Are you sure it's an error and not a warning?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's an error, since I get it both in Visual Studio and Unreal Engine https://imgur.com/a/z0Bdtrb


EDIT: Ahh, sorry, it is indeed a compiler warning, it just shows up as an error, but I can't build my solution nevertheless

Comment: _but I can't build my solution nevertheless_ Because?

Comment: You must have "Treat warnings as errors" enabled.  Check your compiler/linker options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UnrealEngine seems to treat many warnings as errors, so this causes trouble when trying to use with 3rd party libraries that produce those warnings. Usually it's best to fix code to avoid the warning, but I would assume you can't for whatever reason.

In this particular case you could set:

```
bEnableUndefinedIdentifierWarnings = false;
```

Inside your *.Build.cs class constructor.

---

If this wasn't UnrealEngine, but still Visual Studio C++, you could also try putting this before code that causes the warning (e.g. before including header in which you get the warning):

```
#pragma warning(disable: 4668)
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/warning?view=vs-2019

Or disable it as compilation flag:

```
/wd4668
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/compiler-option-warning-level?view=vs-2019

In general, if you get something you feel shouldn't be an error, search web if given error number (here C4668) is not usually a warning. If it is, then this allows quick hacks like above.

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks for the answer! I got a 3rd lib working with Unreal using the mentioned boolean in the constructor! Do understand correctly that the real issue is that Unreal uses higher warning/error flags than most of other c++ applications which upgrades some warning to errors?

Comment: UE4 creators decided to have some additional warnings and set all warnings as errors, so that every fail requires fixing. It's a quite common practice, but usually when you use 3rd party code, only it compiles with those more strict rules - so you don't need to worry about them in your own code. Yet, UE4 has own buildsystem that imposes those rules on your code (including 3rd party libs you add).
The 3rd party lib you add there could use more warning checks than UE4, but unless it's superset of what UE4 has as an error (unlikely), then there is a chance of UE4 complaining about something.